# Adding x work days onto a date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm a bit confused if there is a simple way to do this.

I have a field called receipt_date in my data table and I wish to add 10 working days to this (with bank holidays).

I'm not sure if there is any sort of query I could use to join onto this table from my original to calculate 10 working days from this, I've tried a few sub queries but I couldn't get it right or perhaps its not possible to do this. I didn't know if there was a way to extract the 10th rowcount after the receipt date to get the calendar date if I only include 'Y' into the WHERE?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Show us your table structure (both the one with `receipt_date` and the table "with a load of dates"), a few rows of sample data, desired results, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: `Is there a simple way to do this? ` What is simple for one might be complicated for someone else. So there is no correct answer for that

Comment: The simple answer is that you need to use your table with a load of dates to calculate the number of workdays, and then just add that number to your column value

Comment: I've tried sub querying the data and then adding a rank to get the 10th rank and ordering it by calendar_date and only trying to get the 10th calendar date but that didn't work whihc I kinda understand why

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your data I can't really give you a query; but effectively if you're looking for a date X working days in the future - then you're looking for the date x + y days in the future where y is the number of non-working days.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is making *several* assumptions about your data, because we have none. One method, however, would be to create a function, I use a inline table value function here, to return the relevant row from your calendar table. Note that this *assumes* that the number of days must always be positive, and that if you provide a date that isn't a working day that day `0` would be the next working day. I.e. adding zero working days to `2021-09-05` would return `2021-09-06`, or adding 3 would return `2021-09-09`. If that isn't what you want, this should be more than enough for you to get there yourself.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AddWorkingDays (@Days int, @Date date) 
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
    WITH Dates AS(
        SELECT CalendarDate,
               WorkingDay
        FROM dbo.CalendarTable
        WHERE CalendarDate >= @Date)
    SELECT CalendarDate
    FROM Dates
    WHERE WorkingDay = 1
    ORDER BY CalendarDate
    OFFSET @Days ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
GO

--Using the function

SELECT YT.DateColumn,
       AWD.CalendarDate AS AddedWorkingDays
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.AddWorkingDays(10,YT.DateColumn) AWD;
```

Comment: Hey thanks, would it be workingday = 'Y' however? based on the calendar table

Comment: As I said, I made several assumptions about your data because I have none, @paulr23 . I don't know what *your* calendar table looks like, so you need to alter the above for your environment. I, however, *assumed* that your `WorkingDay` column would be defined as `bit NOT NULL`; because that's the easiest (and smallest) way to denote a true/false type value in SQL Server.

Comment: @paulr23 We don't know, you didn't show us your calendar table. Typically you use `bit` columns rather than `char(1)`, but if you use `Y`/`N`, hopefully you can adjust the query to suit. See [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) and [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/) for tips on creating and using a calendar table.

Comment: @paulr23 Yeah, you should reconsider that design IMHO.

Comment: I would personally, for that requirement, likely have 2 `bit NOT NULL` columns, `Weekday` and `WorkingDay`; using `1` to denote `TRUE`, or "Yes", and `0` the opposite.

Comment: I actually find it easier to put holidays and other outages in a separate table (which allows you to have more than one holiday or outage reason for a given day, and store descriptions etc. for each). But I certainly don't like magic codes like `B`.

Comment: They work *really* well when you're dealing with multiple "locations", @AaronBertrand  . For example, even in the UK, England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland all observe different public holidays; if I were working for a business than wasn't just based in England I would certainly go down the "Holiday Table" methodology.

Comment: Right. I use it also for maintenance windows that don't involve labor per se, like a patching window, company function, sale event etc. And sometimes those intersect with explicit holidays, weekends, etc.

Comment: I have reformatted my original question as I tried the methodology in the post above but it didnt work for whatever reason, it was giving me minus days. I have added my table structures into the post

Comment: Sounds like you changed something incorrectly, with the data you've proviuded, I can't replicate that problem at all, @paulr23 . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68528a4ae01accf2e2462fb796573ffe)

Comment: Is line 12 correct on your function you gave me?

Comment: That should be `CalendarDate`, @paulr23 ; I couldn't test the function before as I had no data (though one would have hoped you would have fixed that in your deployement).

Comment: I did, I just wanted to make sure

Comment: Ok it works thanks. How it works I don't really know though

Comment: It's relatively simply, if I am honest, @paulr23 . The CTE gets all the dates on or after the input date, and then the outer query filters the rows from that data to only working days. Finally the `ORDER BY` uses the `OFFSET` clause to skip by the input number of days in rows, and then only returns 1 row (like a `TOP (1)`).

Comment: It works great thanks, only issue I have is I tried to use the same function for a different field and I get 0 records back for my result set. Not entirely sure why

Comment: That would likely mean the function isn't returning a row, @paulr23 ; perhaps the value in the column you are passing to the function is `NULL`? If a row won't always be returned, use an `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: Yes thanks just been reading up on these, figured its probably best to add outer apply to all 3 of the times I'm using the function as the fields are not always inputted by the users at the first time of adding the record

Comment: If this does answer the question, by the way @paulr23 , please do accept it as the solution. This let's future users know that the answer was helpful. Many thanks.